# View controller is not pushed when I tap on UITableViewCell.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, tableview, viewcontroller

For some reason my navigation controller isn't pushing properly.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"HERE!");
    MyViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myVC"];
    vc.labelText = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Pushed");
}
```

The output is:

```
2014-02-17 12:41:47.187 TableViewTesting[37532:70b] HERE!
2014-02-17 12:41:47.189 TableViewTesting[37532:70b] Pushed
```

So it's all running fine, but I still just see my initial view controller even after tapping on a cell.

Comment: Use the debugger to make sure that `vc` is not `nil`. Also check to see that `self.navigationController` is not `nil`.

Comment: @Gavin, if vc was nil then he would get an exception from instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. The only thing that i see here is that the self.navigationController is nil and that's why nothing happens.

Comment: check for you navigation controller. your controller is embedded in navigation controller or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the view controller from which you are calling this code embedded in the `Navigation Controller`? If it's not, then nothing would happen when you call `pushViewController` method.

Go to your `Storyboard`, select the initial view controller, then from the top bar **Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller** and try again.

Comment: Had some other problems that got in my way, but in the end this actually did solve my problem. Thanks!